# TYPO3 FAL changed image not available in translation

Tags: typo3, translation, typo3-7.6.x, fal

In TYPO3 7.6, when I exchange an image in the base language I am not able to add this image in an already existing translation record.

For example: I added image pic1.jpg in English (`L=0`), on translating to German (`L=1`) `pic1.jpg` is available for activation. Later I remove `pic1.jpg` and add `pic2.jpg`, probably clipping or otherwise modify the relation so I have data that I want to preserve.

I'm able to delete the German translation record and add a new translation in both list view and page->languages:"Add Translation" with new image(s) and all its modifications preserved, but that is a work-around loosing all translated fields in the process.

If my memory doesn't fail me, there was a dimmed FAL record appearing in the translation media tab once it was added in the base language back in former versions of TYPO3 (6.1).

Bug? Or am I missing something?

Comment: This could be this bug: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/57272

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a TYPO3 v7.6 core bug which exists since 2014 but it was never fixed. See bug report: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/57272

There are multiple ways to solve this issue. I had this problem too and for me it only worked with the first solution. 

**1. Create a ViewHelper**
It's a solution from Kai Tallafus who shared his ViewHelper in the comments of the bug report 57272 (see link to bug report above).
ViewHelper: https://forge.typo3.org/attachments/download/32333/FalTranslationFixViewHelper.php
Usage of the ViewHelper in Fluid Template:

```
<util:falTranslationFix record="{record}" tableName="tx_myext_domain_model_foo" relationFieldName="files" as="files">
    <f:if condition="{files -> f:count()} > 0">
      <f:for each="{files}" as="file">
        <a href="{file.publicUrl}">{file.properties.title}</a>
      </f:for>
    </f:if>
</util:falTranslationFix>
```

**2. Install an Extension**
I found two extensions who probably will fix the bug. I recommend the first one but it doesn't work for me but maybe it will for you.

1. repair_translation
2. faltranslation (only available on bitbucket -> bitbucket.org/t3easy_de/faltranslation/src)

**3. Enable sys_language_uid field for the FAL Media**
There is a workaround for the translation of the FAL Media in which you enable the sys_language_uid field. When enabled the enduser can select the language for the media element. This also not worked for me but I know from a friend that in one of his project it worked. 
Manual (in german): www.npostnik.de/typo3/workaround-fuer-uebersetztungen-der-datensaetze-mit-fal-media/

**4. Update to TYPO3 v8 LTS**
When you're working on a project which could be updated to the new Version, you should consider to make an update. The Bug is fixed in the TYPO3 v8 LTS.

Comment: The quickest solution is to install the extension `repair_translation` from Stefan Froemken. But be aware to install version 1.2.2, not the latest: https://github.com/froemken/repair_translation/issues/10  / I've updated from 7.6 to 8.7 and the translation bug is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The viewhelper won't work for the field media in tablep-pair pages/page_labnguage_overlay. (TYPO3 8.7)

You have to seperate your translateted parts in the fluid-template. The where-clause in the query should check for 'pid' instead of 'uid'. And you have to check for a relavant entry in the media-field of the `$rawRecord`.